# Named query with join without input parameters

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpql, named-query

I have been trying for the past few days to convert this sql to named query and failed. Here is the sql

```
select * from EACI ci
LEFT OUTER JOIN EAT eat
ON ci.user_id = eat.user_id 
WHERE ci.commodity_code = eat.commodity_code and ci.auditor_type <> eat.auditor_type and eat.IS_LATEST ='Y'
```

EACI and EAT are not joined directly but through another table User

```
    @NamedQuery(
    name = "ACI.findMismatch", 
    query = "select aci from AuditorCommodityInfo aci "
            + " inner join aci.user user "
            + " inner join fetch user.auditorTrackings tracking "
            + " WHERE tracking.isLatest= 'Y'"
            + " and aci.auditorType <> tracking.auditorType "
            + " and aci.commodity.code = tracking.commodity.code "
            )
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: I don't know if I undertood, but where is the ON Clausure for each JOIN in your string query?

Comment: other thing tha would cause the issue is the 4th, 5th and 7th line where you didn't put de blank space before the sentence...

Comment: My bad, I rephrased my sql but posted the older named query. Updated